# Android Twitter4j Error

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am getting following error while updating my twitter status from java code in android using Twitter4J .

Any help will be appreciated.....

```
09-18 11:34:50.476: WARN/System.err(755): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[15bb6564-00e4d61f], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.5-SNAPSHOT(build: d372a51b9b419cbd73d416474f4a855f3e889507)}
09-18 11:34:50.476: WARN/System.err(755):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:308)
09-18 11:34:50.496: WARN/System.err(755):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:72)
09-18 11:34:50.496: WARN/System.err(755):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
09-18 11:34:50.496: WARN/System.err(755):     at twitter4j.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:500)
09-18 11:34:50.496: WARN/System.err(755):     at com.android.twitterTest.twitterTest.postUpdate(twitterTest.java:115)
09-18 11:34:50.510: WARN/System.err(755):     at com.android.twitterTest.twitterTest$1.onClick(twitterTest.java:50)
09-18 11:34:50.510: WARN/System.err(755):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
09-18 11:34:50.510: WARN/System.err(755):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
09-18 11:34:50.510: WARN/System.err(755):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-18 11:34:50.536: WARN/System.err(755):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 11:34:50.596: INFO/Exception(755): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[15bb6564-00e4d61f], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.5-SNAPSHOT(build: d372a51b9b419cbd73d416474f4a855f3e889507)}
09-18 11:36:38.517: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-18 11:41:38.527: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
09-18 11:42:49.207: DEBUG/ThrottleService(60): onPollAlarm - roaming =false, read =0, written =0, new total =0
09-18 11:46:38.530: DEBUG/SntpClient(60): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem :( Any solution ?

Comment: not able to find any solution till yet....  as soon as i get any, i will post it here

Comment: I have checked it using oAuth but still need to find some way for using username and password................. Check this link http://consultingblogs.emc.com/nileeshabojjawar/archive/2010/03/18/twitter4j-oauth-generating-the-access-token.aspx

Comment: You could check this TUT: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/sending-a-tweet-t54389.html Shows how to use Twitter4J with source files

Answer (score 2):

Per https://apiwiki.twitter.com/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors: `status code 401` means the authentication credentials were missing or incorrect. Make sure you're successfully connecting via OAuth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer............  I got it working...... Twitter was not accepting some changes in settings, so created new app and got it....... Thanks for the answer again .......

Comment: @viv I want to open a dialog to prompt the user to update his status ... Is this possible .. have u implemented this ?? If so please repley to my comment... I am able to update the status .. by passing a messag e but i want the user to enter his own message in a dialog box ... which is similar to COMPOSE TWEET dialog in twitter ..

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 : Check this : http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application , You will find a line twitter.updateStatus(msg); , you can open dialog to allow user to enter message , then pass that to post on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. But signing out and then signing in again worked for me. Now my app is working and error is removed.